# How to bind Ajax control Calender Toolkit to a textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Respected to Sir/Madam,
In aspx page i have taken textbox and attach to it a AjaxCalender by TargetControlId and in java-script file i want to add that textbox according to that ajax calendar control on each row creation.for first row the page will be loaded then that respective calendar control attached to that respective textbox successfully but not able to attach that further rows text-boxes that calendar control so what to do please guide me

Comment: Please show your effort first.

Comment: but how to write code in this site i dont know i have done that work. and previously i asked almost 3,4 questions along with sending code but no one able to give the answer and where to put my code please guide me. and i have one question can we clone ajax calender extender in .net in jquery plz send reply as early as possible

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53169605/edit) your question and add your code.